# spring webflux graphql test giving No qualifying bean of type AnnotatedControllerConfigurer

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-graphql

PFB my code. Getting below error when I run unit test case of below code.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.AnnotatedControllerConfigurer' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

```
@GraphQlTest(controllers = PostGraphQLController.class)
class QueryTests {
    @Autowired
    GraphQlTester graphQlTester;

    @MockBean
    PostServiceImpl postService;
    @MockBean
    RuntimeWiringConfigurer runtimeWiringConfigurer;
    @Test
    void getAllPosts(){
        when(postService.getAllPosts()).thenReturn(Flux.just(
            Post.builder().id(1L)
```